# [SQL][Database] How to count the number of review's id of each star of product in SQL?

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables, Products and Review. There are those attributes: 
Product( id (PK), name) 
Review( id(PK), prod_id(FK), name) 
Sample data for Products

```
+--------+----------+
|id      |name      |
+--------+----------+
|1       |fruit     |
|2       |milk      |
|3       |clothes   |
+--------+----------+
```

Sample data for Review

```
+---+--------+-----+
|id |prod_id |star |
+---+--------+-----+
|1  |1       |5    |
|2  |1       |5    |
|3  |1       |5    |
|4  |1       |4    |
|5  |1       |4    |
|6  |1       |1    |
|7  |2       |5    |
|8  |2       |2    |
|9  |3       |5    |
|10 |3       |5    |
|11 |3       |5    |
+---+--------+-----+
```

I want to count the number of review's id of each star group by product's id 
The goal I want:

```
+--------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+---------+
|prod_id |five_star |four_star |three_star |two_star |one_star |
+--------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+---------+
|1       |3         |2         |0          |0        |1        |
|2       |1         |0         |0          |1        |0        |
|3       |3         |0         |0          |0        |0        |
+--------+----------+----------+-----------+---------+---------+
```

I have tried to use this query but it's not right:

```
select R.prod_id,
    count(distinct case when R.star = 5 then R.id else 0 end) as five,
    count(distinct case when R.star = 4 then R.id else 0 end) as four,
    count(distinct case when R.star = 3 then R.id else 0 end) as three,
    count(distinct case when R.star = 2 then R.id else 0 end) as two,
    count(distinct case when R.star = 1 then R.id else 0 end) as one
from Review as R 
group by R.prod_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is on the right track, but you need conditional counts:

```sql
SELECT
    prod_id,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN star = 5 THEN 1 END) AS five,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN star = 4 THEN 1 END) AS four,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN star = 3 THEN 1 END) AS three,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN star = 2 THEN 1 END) AS two,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN star = 1 THEN 1 END) AS one
FROM Review
GROUP BY
    prod_id;
```